# rcu: messages during startup

Tags: server, 23.04

For a few months now I get two lines of rcu: messages in log and also showing on log-in screen as well on my Ubuntu server.

They seem to appear when the system is loading docker:
[from syslog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N83MZ.png)

The system seems to run as normal, but would still like to know what cause them to trigger and how to get rid of them.

Thank you.